# How can I convert a collection of asciidoc files into a unified html file?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

We are currently using the asciidoc format to document pertinent info for our products - each info section stored as adoc files. Then we use a makefile to run the asciidoctor tool to create html files for each changed adoc file.

However, I'd like to combine all adoc files into one unified html file.

I thought maybe I could create a book based on the adoc files, but the following doesn't appear to work:

```
asciidoctor --doctype=book --out-file=book.html file1.adoc file2.adoc dir1/file3.adoc
```

This results in the last adoc file (dir/file3.adoc) making up the book.html file, instead of including all the specified adoc files.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to join the files into one. The simplistic approach would be to:

```sh
cat *.adoc > all_in_one.adoc
```

Unfortunately, a single Asciidoc file can only have one top-level title. Each of your existing Asciidoc files likely already has a top-level title.

I would suggest creating a "master" document that uses the `include` macro to "include" the content of each file. You can use the `leveloffset` attribute in each include to prevent warnings about multiple top-level titles.

For example, you can gather all of the Asciidoc filenames into a single file, like this:

```sh
find . -name '*.adoc' > all_in_one.adoc
```

Then edit the file, which might look like this:

```
./a.adoc
./B/b.adoc
./c.adoc
...
```

To something like this:

```
= Top-level title

include::./a.adoc[leveloffset=1]
include::./B/b.adoc[leveloffset=1]
include::./c.adoc[leveloffset=1]
...
```

One additional problem: If there are multiple section titles with the same id, or the same name and that use an auto-generated id, you'll see warnings about `id assigned to section already in use`. You'll have to add custom id, or adjust the text of the titles to be distinct, as appropriate.